# get the public image by Instagram API

Tags: api, instagram

How to Search the public images by Instagram API

I am trying the same but getting this BY 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/sachin/media/recent/?access_token=

Comment: which API method  shall I use

Comment: Show what you tried, and your own code.